# Custom ContentProvider in own process not always available

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am working on an android application that has 3 major processes.

The main UI, **U**, runs in its own process.

A content provider, **C**, running in its own process

And a service, **S**, running in another process.

Both **U** and **S** access an sqlite database containing about 6 tables through the content provider, **C**.

The issue I have is that **C** is not always available and this causes some queries to fail, at times.

I had to make an hack that makes a query to the `ContentProvider`, **C**, and checks for a boolean variable, set in the `ContentProvider's` `SQLiteOpenHelper` that becomes true when **C**'s onCreate has been called and its `SQLiteOpenHelper` has been fully initialized too and is ready to be used by **C** for queries.

This works nice, but it is so stressful and I cant imagine applying it to all the points in **U** and **S**, where **C** is accessed.

> How can I ensure that **C** is always up for **U** and **S** to use? 
>   especially as it seems as if **C** can be up now and down later on?

**PLEASE NOTE** 
The ContentProvider works fine whenever it is actually up and when it goes off,  no exception whatsoever is thrown.

Here is the manifest entry for **C**

```
    <provider
                android:name=".data.cprov.Provider"     
 android:authorities="mynet.app.data.cprov.Provider"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="false"
                android:process=":someproc"
    android:permission="mynet.app.data.PERMISSION"
                />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after some experimentation, I figured out that the **Android OS** might have been wired to kill off a content provider if it has not been used for a while.  I believe I read something like this somewhere on **StackOverFlow** some days back.

In order to make the content provider available on demand as my scenario required,
I did the following.

First, I included a static boolean variable called `initializationRunning` in the `ContentProvider's` `SQLiteOpenHelper` which is set to false once the SQLiteOpenHelper has been fully initialized by the `ContentProvider`.

This ensures that both the `ContentProvider` and its `SQLiteOpenHelper` are fully prepared for use.

Then I created an additional URI which makes this variable(`initializationRunning`) accessible to my other processes.

I return this variable through a `MatrixCursor` or other appropriate `Cursor`

in the `ContentProvider's` `query` method.

```
public class ChatsProvider extends ContentProvider {


    public static final String AUTHORITY = "mynet.app.data.cprov.Provider;

    private static final String CHATS_TABLE = "CHATS";
    private static final String CONTACTS_TABLE = "CONTACTS;
    private static final String UPDATES_TABLE = "UPDATES";
    private static final String UPLOADED_CONTACTS_TABLE = "UPLOADED_CONTACTS";
    private static final String PRODUCTS_TABLE = "PRODUCTS";
    private static final String ROOMS_TABLE = "ROOMS";


    private static final String MOCK_TABLE = "MOCK";



    public static final String MOCK_COLUMN = "MOCK_COLUMN";




    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_CHATS =
            Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + CHATS_TABLE);
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_CONTACTS =
            Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + CONTACTS_TABLE);
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_UPDATES =
            Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + UPDATES_TABLE);
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_UPLOADED_CONTACTS =
            Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + UPLOADED_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_PRODUCTS =
            Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + PRODUCTS_TABLE);
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_ROOMS =
            Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + ROOMS_TABLE);

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_MOCK =
            Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + MOCK_TABLE);


    public static final int CHATS = 1;
    public static final int CHATS_ID = 100;


    public static final int CONTACTS = 101;
    public static final int CONTACTS_ID = 200;

    public static final int UPDATES = 201;
    public static final int UPDATES_ID = 300;

    public static final int UPLOADED_CONTACTS = 301;
    public static final int UPLOADED_CONTACTS_ID = 400;

    public static final int PRODUCTS = 401;
    public static final int PRODUCTS_ID = 500;

    public static final int ROOMS = 501;
    public static final int ROOMS_ID = 600;


    public static final int MOCK = 601;
    public static final int MOCK_ID = 700;













    private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
/**
 * My SQLiteOpenHelper
 */
    public static DatabaseUtils databaseUtils;

    static {
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, CHATS_TABLE, CHATS);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, CHATS_TABLE + "/#",
                CHATS_ID);

        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, CONTACTS_TABLE, CONTACTS);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, CONTACTS_TABLE + "/#",
                CONTACTS_ID);

        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, UPDATES_TABLE, UPDATES);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, UPDATES_TABLE + "/#",
                UPDATES_ID);

        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, UPLOADED_CONTACTS_TABLE, UPLOADED_CONTACTS);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, UPLOADED_CONTACTS_TABLE + "/#",
                UPLOADED_CONTACTS_ID);

        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, PRODUCTS_TABLE, PRODUCTS);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, PRODUCTS_TABLE + "/#",
                PRODUCTS_ID);

        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, ROOMS_TABLE, ROOMS);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, ROOMS_TABLE + "/#",
                ROOMS_ID);


        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, MOCK_TABLE, MOCK);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, MOCK_TABLE + "/#",
                MOCK_ID);

    }





    public ChatsProvider() {
    }


    @Override
    public synchronized boolean onCreate() {
        Utils.logErrorMessage("ContentProvider-"+this+" is up and running!", getClass());
        if(databaseUtils == null){
            databaseUtils = DatabaseUtils.getInstance(this.getContext());
        }
        return false;
    }



    @Override
    public synchronized Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        int uriType = uriMatcher.match(uri);
        String table = null;
        switch (uriType) {
            case CHATS:
                table = CHATS_TABLE;
                break;
            case CONTACTS:
                table = CONTACTS_TABLE;
                break;
            case UPDATES:
                table = UPDATES_TABLE;
                break;
            case UPLOADED_CONTACTS:
                table = UPLOADED_CONTACTS_TABLE;
                break;
            case PRODUCTS:
                table = PRODUCTS_TABLE;
                break;
            case ROOMS:
                table = ROOMS_TABLE;
                break;
            case MOCK:
                table = MOCK_TABLE;
                break;

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        if(table.equals(MOCK_TABLE)){
            String[] value = { DatabaseUtils.initializationRunning + "" };
            String[] mockProjection = new String[]{"MOCK_COLUMN"};
            MatrixCursor c = new MatrixCursor(mockProjection);
            c.addRow(value);
            return c;
        }
        try {
            SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
            queryBuilder.setTables(table);

            Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
            cursor.setNotificationUri(AppController.contentResolver,
                    uri);
            return cursor;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Now, in my Application singleton instance, I detect if the current running process is my Service's process or my UI's process.

For both cases, I do something like:

```
int count = 0;
while(  !checkContentProviderReady() ){++count;}
```

This has the effect of "rousing" the `ContentProvider` from sleep, or rather, it encourages the **Android OS** to create the ContentProvider or something.

The method, `checkContentProviderReady()`  is simply a method that queries the `ContentProvider` for the `initializationRunning` variable to know when it is false.

Immediately after this, I start a thread in the `Application class` (for the `Service's` process and the main `UI's` process which calls the  `checkContentProviderReady()` method every 5 seconds.

This forces the **Android OS** to believe that the `ContentProvider` is been used regularly and so it leaves it alive.

Well, I don't know if this will help your app, but it sure helped mine.

**The summary of this?**

Create a non-expensive method in your `ContentProvider` and have a timed method in your clients call it periodically(not too fast!).

In my case because I needed to know that the database helper was ready, I also returned the state of the database helper in the timed method call.

Thanks!